# Phonegap "Indexeddb" Database

Tags: indexeddb

Can I use in **Phonegap "Indexeddb" Database**?

I have sample example that run perfectly on chrome (desktop), while I put it (using phonegap build) on my device (i test both ios and android) it doesn't work at all.

*Any idea?
thanks*

Comment: Have you added any logging to your application? [Check debugging in PhoneGap](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/Debugging-in-PhoneGap)

Answer (score 1):

iOS and some older versions of Android don't support indexedDB. On Android 4.x an older version is implemented but on Android 4.4 it should work.
I use a polyfill for iOS and Android which actually uses websql. The polyfill adds the indexedDB API while I isn't actually supported and converts the calls to websql. This works on both Android and iOS!

websql is supported on android 2+ and iOS 4, if I remember correctly. See the indexedDBShim for details: https://github.com/axemclion/IndexedDBShim/

Note: The polyfill isn't perfect, not all methods support an IDDBKeyRange but you can workaround it in most cases.